Vercel stop working from previous few commits that my collaboraters made
So we were working on  a HTML, CSS and JS project, I hosted it in vercel in my vercel account.
His previous commits were being applied and also in other past repo, we had no problem as he could commit and his changes were being applied perfectly.
For from past few commits, only mine commits are being depoyed in vercel.
When he commits, it just shows cross in the commit and with message:
"Git author  must have access to the project on Vercel to create deployments."
This is strange cause previously his commits were being applied but for few days, it's not. What maybe the issue?

I found out what was the issue. Vercel have made some changes in their free plan now and we can't do that with collaborators anymore in the free version.
